# 2022 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #4](https://french.stackexchange.com/election/4) on French Language has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: anonymous2]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://french.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking the following user, who will be stepping down as moderator:

[image: Reyedy]

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://french.stackexchange.com/election/4) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4687205237784576).

Comment: Congratulations to our newly elected diamond user!

Comment: Thank you to everyone who voted! Also a huge thank you to Reyedy for their 2 years of moderation, and to β.εηοιτ.βε and jihedgasmi for their willingness to pitch in!

Comment: Congratulations @anonymous2! Good luck for the upcoming work and thank you for stepping up to help the community. :)